# Digital camera not detected via USB

Tags: usb

DSLR Camera is not detected when connected via usb. lsusb shows same results with device connected/disconnected. dmesg indicates nothing after connecting via usb.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, what model of DSLR and on which version of Ubuntu, give us some more clues.

Comment: DSLR is a Nikon 3400. Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: I think I saw the USB mode selector in the Camera system, can you switch to MSC from PTP. https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/na/NSG_article?articleNo=000025693&lang=en_SG If it doesn't work, ask Nikon about it.